# Error : keras.backend has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'

Tags: python, keras, backend, conv-neural-network

when try to do `set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

```
from keras import backend as K

K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

I got attribute error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please try to post the error as _text_ not as an image. Also please try to include as much context as possible to help people answer your question. What `keras` library version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
```

The latest version has replaced the `image_dim_ordering` to `image_data_format`.

For more info refer to thies [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12649)